# How to disable week ends ( Sunday & Saturday ) for DateRangePicker?

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

```
<DateRangePicker
  value={this.state.value}
  onSelect={this.onSelect}
  singleDateRange={true}
  minimumDate={new Date()}
  firstOfWeek={0}
/>
```

How do i disable the weekend days for the datepicker in this library: [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates)

Please help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: Edited for formatting and context

Comment: I have assumed what library you are using from your code, if that is not correct, please edit your question with the correct library

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DayPicker` that will be easy

```
export default function Example() {
  return (
    <DayPicker
      initialMonth={new Date(2017, 3)}
      disabledDays={[new Date(2017, 3, 12), { daysOfWeek: [0, 6] }]}
    />
  );
}
```

[This](https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/disabled-weekends/) is how you will disable weakends

Comment: Thanks for reply.the above code lines i have used but it's not working.if you have any alternative share me.

Comment: when i am selecting the range of dates in DateRangePicker,Saturday and Sunday are also selecting in the range,i don't want to select the weekends.

Comment: a link is also there in the answer you can look at that as well